# overlay bar chart, loops takes too long

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my code:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



fig, ax = plt.subplots()

list_date = ['2015', '2016', '2017']

data_dict_A = {'2015': {1: 254, 2:567, 3:786}, 
             '2016':{1:567, 2:189, 3:145},
             '2017': {1:89, 2:123, 3:190}}
data_dict_B = {'2015': {1: 154, 2:597, 3:286}, 
             '2016':{1:967, 2:789, 3:345},
             '2017': {1:189, 2:223, 3:290}}
data_dict_C = {'2015': {1: 354, 2:591, 3:486}, 
             '2016':{1:267, 2:289, 3:367},
             '2017': {1:489, 2:256, 3:390}}

length = np.arange(1, 4, 1)
width = 0.2

for each_date in list_date:
    for d_A, v_A in data_dict_A.items():
        for d_B, v_B in data_dict_B.items():
            for d_C, v_C in data_dict_C.items():
                if each_date in data_dict_A.keys():
                    graph_A = plt.bar(length-0.2, v_A.values(), width, color="blue", align='center')
                    graph_B = plt.bar(length, v_B.values(), width, color="red", align='center')
                    graph_C = plt.bar(length+0.2, v_C.values(), width, color="yellow", align='center')
                    plt.legend((graph_A[0], graph_B[0], graph_C[0]), ('A', 'B', 'C'), loc='best')
                    plt.title(str(each_date))
                    fig.savefig( str(each_date) +'.png')
```

If you run this code, it does not appear what I want. For example: I want to have a separate graph on '2015', '2016, and '2017'! The x-axis will be "1", "2", "3" while the y-value will be key value of them.

When you run this code, there is an overlap on the graph that graph of year 2015 is overlayed on 2016 and 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I've restructured it a little, and it seems to work. The key thing is that at the end of the `each_date` loop, you need to clear the figure (`clf`). Also, your loop `for d_A, v_A in data_dict_A.items()` loops over all dates, so you need to check the date `d_A` is the same as `each_date`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

list_date = ['2015', '2016', '2017']

data_dict_A = {'2015': {1: 254, 2:567, 3:786}, 
             '2016':{1:567, 2:189, 3:145},
             '2017': {1:89, 2:123, 3:190}}
data_dict_B = {'2015': {1: 154, 2:597, 3:286}, 
             '2016':{1:967, 2:789, 3:345},
             '2017': {1:189, 2:223, 3:290}}
data_dict_C = {'2015': {1: 354, 2:591, 3:486}, 
             '2016':{1:267, 2:289, 3:367},
             '2017': {1:489, 2:256, 3:390}}

length = np.arange(1, 4, 1)
width = 0.2

for each_date in list_date:
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    for d_A, v_A in data_dict_A.items():
        if d_A == each_date:
            graph_A = plt.bar(length-0.2, v_A.values(), width, color="blue", align='center')

    for d_B, v_B in data_dict_B.items():
        if d_B == each_date:
            graph_B = plt.bar(length, v_B.values(), width, color="red", align='center')

    for d_C, v_C in data_dict_C.items():
        if d_C == each_date:
            graph_C = plt.bar(length+0.2, v_C.values(), width, color="yellow", align='center')

    plt.legend((graph_A[0], graph_B[0], graph_C[0]), ('A', 'B', 'C'), loc='best')
    plt.title(str(each_date))
    fig.savefig( str(each_date) +'.png')
    fig.clf()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]